# Joomla Site Runs on VPS, but NOT on local Mac 10.11 el capitan

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, osx-elcapitan

I downloaded my live site to my development environment on my local machine.
I am able to log into my account on the local Joomla site with credentials that came from the live site. Admin panel works fine. When I try to register a new account on the local site, the registration page loads and looks perfect just like on the live site, but when you try to submit the form, the submit button is not working.

I am connected to my local database. I have been through php.ini, and Apache config files over and over again, and I can't figure this out.

Comment: Hello, have you update you log and tmp dir in your config file? If you open your browsers console what do you see when submitting?

Comment: Yes. Log and tmp dirs updated.  Nothing shows in the console when clicking the button.  Mouse over hover and it appears to be a button, but when clicked, nothing.  It is also not validating that a username already exists like the live site does.

Comment: Sounds like a js issue. Compare the loaded scripts on both sites and also the form action

Comment: It is a direct download of the live site.  How could the scripts vary at all? I'm curious if there is a server setting that I am missing, although that is all I've been looking at for the last 48 hours to no avail.

Comment: Well... Regretfully, I re-installed MAMP, and at first no progress... But after about 30 minutes of tinkering, success. I wish I could say I know what the problem is/was, but I don't.  Any suggestions as to how to compare the instances would be appreciated. I have copies of all.

Comment: It could be the template has hard coded urls or the site does. Mamp works very well so shouldn't be that.